# Turn this string into DateTime object

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am getting passed date variables from facebook api as a string like this:

```
2014-05-15T20:36:03+0000
```

Is that a set format that I can convert directly into a DateTime object or do I have to break apart the string?

Comment: `DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2014-05-15T20:36:03+0000");` this should do it

Comment: It did indeed!  Thank you very much

Comment: @Guerrilla - Watch the offset. If you just use `Convert.ToDateTime` or `DateTime.Parse` without any arguments, the resulting `DateTime` will adjust the time based on that offset using your local computer's time zone.  The better approach is to parse as a `DateTimeOffset` (see the duplicate).  You can take the `DateTime` from there if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to parse the string to a datetime object.

```
DateTime.Parse("2014-05-15T20:36:03+0000")
```